# Where are DPM backups stored in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault, dpm

I have configured Azure Recovery Services Vault to backup data from an on-premise DPM. I can see which servers and databases are being backed up but I cannot find the location of it in Azure. I am looking for this because I want to know how much I will be charged for these backup storage costs.

Does anyone know how I can find this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it here:
Azure-- Recovery Service Vault-- Backup Infrastructure--Backup Management Server.
Click on your DPM Server, you can see used space.
For the costs go back to your Resource Group where the RecoveryServiceVault resides, and go on Cost Analysis.